# how to find a particular pattern in the content of the text file in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone please help for above question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a little more?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to use a combination of [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) to read the text from the file and [RegEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to match the pattern.

It would be difficult to give you any examples since you don't provide any exact details.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a regular expression in order to do it, but perhaps i didn't understand the question..

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions to find any pattern. A tutorial can be found here: http://dotnetperls.com/regex-file

Answer (score 1):

- Use `File.ReadAllText()` to read the content.
- Use `Regex.Matches(`) to look for the pattern.